# Change BeginForm action based on viewdata in partialview?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, view, partial-views

I have a partial view that exists multiple times on the same page. This is added to the view :

```
@Html.Partial("PersonalTagPartial", Model.PT, new ViewDataDictionary{{"TagTypeControl", 1}} )

@Html.Partial("PersonalTagPartial", Model.PT, new ViewDataDictionary{{"TagTypeControl", 0}} )
```

Then in the partialview I got a submit form like this :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddPersonalTag", "Post", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmAddPersonalTags" })){
```

How do I change the AddPersonalTag to RemovePersonalTag when TagTypeControl is set to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm((ViewBag.TagTypeControl == "1" ? "AddPersonalTag" : "RemovePersonalTag"), "Post", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmAddPersonalTags" }))
{
    ...
}
```

but you could also directly pass the action name to the partial:

```
@Html.Partial("PersonalTagPartial", Model.PT, new ViewDataDictionary { { "SubmitTo", "AddPersonalTag" } })
@Html.Partial("PersonalTagPartial", Model.PT, new ViewDataDictionary { { "SubmitTo", "RemovePersonalTag" } })
```

and then inside the partial:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(ViewBag.SubmitTo, "Post", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmAddPersonalTags" }))
{
    ...
}
```